# Showing that $(X_n)$ is a submartingale if and only if $(-X_n)$ is a supermartingale

Tags: measure-theory, martingales

I was reading up on submartingales and supermartingales and saw this statement which I do not understand.

A stochastic process $(X_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is a submartingale with respect to a filtration 
$(\mathcal{F}_n)_{n\geq 1}$ if and only if $(-X_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is a supermartingale with respect to $(\mathcal{F}_n)_{n\geq 1}$.

Need some explanation on this statement. Don't really understand the meaning behind the statement

Comment: From your numerous recent questions on the subject, I suspect you should really make sure you understand in-depth the notion of conditional expectation. That you stumble upon the most obvious E[-X|G]=-E[X|G] shows that something is not right here. To begin with, how would you define E[X|G] in general?

Comment: E[X|G] is an random variable itself and it is the expectation of conditional probability. Is it correct?

Comment: To define the relatively simple notion of conditional expectation E[X|G], you are invoking the much more elaborate notion of conditional probability (in fact, conditional distribution conditionally on a sigma-algebra, but whatever). Just as I feared. Suggestion: learn things in their logical order. Question: which textbook are you using?

Comment: Learning from lecture notes.It is taken from many books. But I am reading from lecture notes. Any good suggestion? Btw, how to define E[X|G] in general?

Comment: No definition of E[X|G] in the "many books" and "lecture notes" you are using? Should I believe you?

Comment: only mathematical definition. no intuitive meaning. mathematical ->  it should be integrable, G-measurable, and satisfy the equation in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation under the formal definiton..

Comment: And you can't solve the present question? Sorry but I simply don't get it.

Comment: I understand the definition, but when it comes to application, I am still lacking.. I am still new to this topic...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A process $(X_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is a sub/super-martingale with respect to $(\mathcal{F}_n)$ if

1. $(X_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is adapted to $(\mathcal{F}_n)_{n\geq 1}$
2. $X_n$ is integrable for every $n\geq 1$
3. ${\rm E}[X_{n+1}\mid\mathcal{F}_n]\geq X_n$ (sub) or ${\rm E}[X_{n+1}\mid\mathcal{F}_n]\leq X_n$ (super) for every $n\geq 1$.

Assume that $(X_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is a sub-martingale. Then we have to argue that $(-X_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is a super-martingale. It clearly satisfies 1 and 2 (why?). As for the last item, we just have to show that for all $n\geq 1$:
$$
{\rm E}[-X_{n+1}\mid\mathcal{F}_n]\leq -X_n
$$
using that we know ${\rm E}[X_{n+1}\mid\mathcal{F}_n]\geq X_n$. This is pretty obvious, isn't it?

Comment: it is just multiplying by negative sign on both sides of ${\rm E}[X_{n+1}\mid\mathcal{F}_n]\geq X_n$ Am i right?

Comment: @lakesh: Yes and then taking the minus-sign inside of the conditional expectation.

Comment: but I am not how to prove the first point?

Comment: Stefan thanks a lot...

Comment: For 1: You have to show that $-X_n$ is $\mathcal{F}_n$-measurable for every $n$. But you know that $X_n$ is $\mathcal{F}_n$-measurable and hence...

Comment: by multiplying negative sign it is still $F_n$ measurable?

Comment: Yes. Multiplication of _any_ constant preserves measurability.